# Dynamically setting statically referenced files as 'active'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Currently I'm working on a web-shop project. For this project an import functionality should be implemented. A large portion of the import logic is already pre-defined. The import task itself is a command line job (artisan), for which the command and possible parameters are also pre-defined.

An important part of the import is the mapping file, which maps the fields in the input (uploaded export file of another web-shop) to the fields in the database.

The framework I'm using (Aimeos for Laravel) only allows for one mapping file to be configured. What I'm trying to do, is let the user specify from what version of what web-shop they are importing products (and other data) and use the appropriate mapping file for the task.

I've build a form in the admin panel where the user can specify the source web-shop type and version and upload a file. When the user presses the 'import' button, an artisan command is called, which will start the import process. This process will look for a specific mapping file at a configured location.

However, depending on the settings the user provided, the required mapping file location will differ. I have no way of passing parameters to the artisan task (command), as it's predefined with specific parameters in the core of the framework, and I don't want to override it, since it's a very crucial and globally used command. It's also used for running other jobs. I can't have it happen that an update will break my override.

So my solution for now is: according to the user specified version and type of web-shop, I rename the corresponding mapping file, let's say xCart v5.3.4.5, to be xcart_5.3.4.5.active.php. In the controller which will run the task, I then look for a mapping file with active in the name. If a user uploads another file after that, and selects another type or version of a web-shop, I rename xcart_5.3.4.5.active.php back to xcart_5.3.4.5.php. And the new required mapping file, let's say ccvshop_11.2.php to ccvshop_11.2.active.php.

However, I'm almost certain that this is not the way to go. There must be a better way of doing this, but I don't know how.

Another way I could do it, would be to dynamically update the contents of the configuration file, which contains a php array. But I know no way of implementing this, while making sure it will work with a 100% certainty. For this I would need to write contents to the configuration file, which is used for the entire web-shop. If it gets corrupted, the entire web-shop will break.

My question is actually really simple. Do you guys have any suggestion on how to solve this issue. The solution should be fail-proof. Please don't be blinded by my solutions as these are probably not the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set config values on the fly by using the `config` helper.

```
config([$key => $value]):
```

$key would be the dot notation path to the config index and $value can be anything, string, int, array, etc.

This is only for the request lifecycle though, it doesn't persist your changes to disk.

To save your changes you could use the File or Storage facades.

```
   File::put(app_path() . '/config/customization.php', $config);
```